# How to check whether file already in use C# Win CE 6

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am using this piece of code to check whether a file already in use but it does not work.

```
protected bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file) {
    FileStream stream = null;

    try {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
    } catch (IOException) {
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Then i tried renaming the file while it's being copied but still it does not throw any exceptions.

```
 protected bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file) {
    string renameToFileName = string.Empty;
    bool isFileLocked = true;
    int i = 0;
    while (isFileLocked) {
        i++;
        renameToFileName = file.FullName + i.ToString();

        try {
            File.Move(file.FullName, renameToFileName);
            isFileLocked = false;
        } catch (Exception) {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    File.Move(renameToFileName, file.FullName);
}
```

Surprisingly the file gets renamed successfully while it's being copied from another process.

Does anybody know how to do this? Please advice

Comment: Renaming locked files in Windows is supported.  Only the data in the file is locked, not the directory entry.  You don't have a problem.